# Find applications that are "calling home"

Tags: security, web-server

I have some compiled applications on my (Linux) Web server and some of them are "calling home". Is there a tool to find out witch file exactly is calling home?

What I want to find are connections that are not to the IP who requested the site.
Like for example when someone requests a site and that site is including a third party site or is trowing some variables in a API somewhere else...

I want to log all outgoing traffic that is not to the requesting IP.
Is there some special tool fot that or can I cover this with "onboard" tools ?

UPDATE:
=======
Is there a way to log the trafic of just a file/folder ?
Is this called a sniffer ?

Answer (score 2):

Talk to the developer and ask them to identify and justify what they are doing. Ask to look at the source code if you do not have it. Review the license agreement, and negotiate better terms if it allows things you do not want.

If you do not trust them, or want to trust and verify, the tool set includes whatever is necessary to understand the application and fight data exfiltration.

- Logging firewall
- Packet capture
- Client developer analysis (presumably there is client side stuff in the browser, but you did not specify)
- Reverse engineering server components in particular

Comment: Is there a way to log the trafic of just a file/folder ? Is this called a sniffer ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add much more detail about your environment. Which web server on which Linux distro, what the application looks like, what indicators of compromise tipped you off, and so on.  Security oriented proxies and analysis tools are a thing, but you have not done your homework.